# what is map and level in im2bw in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to convert RGB image to binary image for processing in matlab , 
its important to choose variables  exactly, 
so I need to know exacly what is map and level in im2bw(x,map,level) ?

Comment: What about http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/images/ref/im2bw.html ?

Comment: @NKN I read that before asking , but map isn't clear

Comment: it specifies the image's colormap. For example you did a plot and applied a `hot` colormap to it, by specifying this to the `im2bw` it can use the information to make the `bw` image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map is used only when the image is of map datatype. Essentially map is a format of storing images where each pixel is represented by a number. The numbers are stored in a lookup table called map. The map images are often more compressible than regular images. When the image has to be displayed, the value of pixel is displayed based on the lookup table.

In this case, im2bw just looks at the greyscale value of each pixel and then thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

The level is the greythresh of the image [0-1].  It can be used to change the luminescence of the image.

The map is a colormap.  Here is the information from mathworks:
"A colormap is an m-by-3 matrix of real numbers between 0.0 and 1.0. Each row is an RGB vector that defines one color. The kth row of the colormap defines the kth color, where map(k,:) = [r(k) g(k) b(k)]) specifies the intensity of red, green, and blue."

The colormap can be used to change the image's colors.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html

Comment: what map means  in im2bw ? we want to convert to binary matrix  that all element are 0 or 1

Comment: It is a colormap. The second link is provides a deeper description of colormaps.

Comment: yes map is color map but how it effect on converting to BINARY matrix.

Comment: I like to think of it as a color filter.  You don't have to use map at all.  There are two other ways to use im2bw
BW = im2bw(I, level)
BW = im2bw(RGB, level)